# Python equivalent of wrapping POST payload in single quotes

Tags: python, json, splunk

This is more of a python question than Splunk but would be helpful if anyone had done this... specifically [here](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/7.2.3/Data/Sendmetricstoametricsindex), there's a discussion of sending multiple metrics in a single POST to the server. The example they provide is using curl and wrapping the entire payload in single quotes ('), e.g.

```
curl -k http://<IP address or host name or load balancer name>:8088/services/collector  \
-H "Authorization: Splunk 98a1e071-bc35-410b-8642-78ce7d829083"                         
\
-d '{"time": 1505501013.000,"source":"disk","host":"host_99","fields": 
{"region":"us-west-1","datacenter":"us-west- 1a","rack":"63","os":"Ubuntu16.10","arch":"x64","team":"LON","service":"6","service_version":"0","service_environment":"test","path":"/dev/sda1","fstype":"ext3","_value":999311222774,"metric_name":"total"}}
{"time": 1505511013.000,"source":"disk","host":"host_99","fields": 
{"region":"us-west-1","datacenter":"us-west-1a","rack":"63","os":"Ubuntu16.10","arch":"x64","team":"LON","service":"6","service_version":"0","service_environment":"test","path":"/dev/sda1","fstype":"ext3","_value":1099511627776,"metric_name":"total"}}'
```

My question is how to do the same thing in python – i.e. you can't wrap multiple JSON objects in single quotes like in the curl command - that just makes the entire payload a string. Is there some other wrapper that can be used for this purpose?

So, this works:

```
payload = {"time": 1505501013.000,"source":"disk","host":"host_99","fields": 
{"region":"us-west-1","datacenter":"us-west- 1a","rack":"63","os":"Ubuntu16.10","arch":"x64","team":"LON","service":"6","service_version":"0","service_environment":"test","path":"/dev/sda1","fstype":"ext3","_value":999311222774,"metric_name":"total"}}
```

But this does not:

```
payload = {"time": 1505501013.000,"source":"disk","host":"host_99","fields": 
{"region":"us-west-1","datacenter":"us-west- 1a","rack":"63","os":"Ubuntu16.10","arch":"x64","team":"LON","service":"6","service_version":"0","service_environment":"test","path":"/dev/sda1","fstype":"ext3","_value":999311222774,"metric_name":"total"}}
 {"time": 1505511013.000,"source":"disk","host":"host_99","fields": 
{"region":"us-west-1","datacenter":"us-west-1a","rack":"63","os":"Ubuntu16.10","arch":"x64","team":"LON","service":"6","service_version":"0","service_environment":"test","path":"/dev/sda1","fstype":"ext3","_value":1099511627776,"metric_name":"total"}}
```

FYI, then the POST looks like:

```
 resp = requests.post(splunkurl,json=payload,headers=headers)
```

Comment: You are confusing the Python `dict` literals with their JSON encodings. With `curl`, you are providing two concatenated JSON objects; in Python, `payload` is a `dict`, not a JSON object.

Comment: fair enough, then question is how to concatenate two dict...

Comment: You can't; the concatenation of two dicts, unlike the concatenation of two JSON objets, is undefined. There is no Python equivalent to what your API accepts as a payload.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, "multiple json objects" is not a valid json, until it's a *list* of objects.

Generally, python doesn't care (just like any other network tool), json is just data format, and you need a different one. So you need to construct text payload yourself, i.e. `json.dumps(payload1) + json.dumps(payload2)`, and send it via your network client as "raw" data.

I highly doubt that mainstream http libraries provide such usecase out of the box.

---

Not sure on reason for downvotes, i.e. [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library (which is kinda standard de-facto for high-level networking) have smart processing for payloads:

```
requests.post(url, data={'v1': 1, 'v2': 2})  # will encode it as form data
requests.post(url, json={'v1': 1, 'v2': 2})  # will encode as json
requests.post(url, data="{'v1': 1}{'v2': 2}")  # will send as-is
```

Json has nothing to do with http itself, it's just a way to serialize data. Most clients will eventually use `urllib`, which doesn't care at all, the only question is if library gives easy way to send data raw

Comment: Thanks, tried this but API does not seem to like that - gets a 400 ("invalid data format") error. Sounds like there is no way to do this in python.

Comment: Thanks for the additional comment. Use data=payload instead of json=payload does in fact work.